# How do you know when Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute has finished executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, jruby

I am running a cucumber script by executing `Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!`

But Ruby moves to the next line and starts reading from the file. But the file is empty as cucumber takes time to process the `Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!`

How to make execution stop until Cucumber has finished executing the script and finished populating the file with HTML. Thank you

Here is the Link for Source Code: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'tempfile'
require 'securerandom'

filename = "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}"
file = Tempfile.new(filename)
filepath = "#{file.path}"
features = "features/login.feature"
args = features.split.concat %w(--format html --out)
args << "#{filepath}.html"

begin
  Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!
  @value = file.read 
ensure
  file.close
  file.unlink
end
```

**EDIT:**

When `Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!` finishes executing it throws a SystemExit Exception with a status 0.

> Exit code is 0 when execution went fine

Cucumber always throws an SystemExit exception when it finishes.

Here is the Link for Source Code for Cucumber: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb

How to handle the SystemExit Exception in Rails, so that it doesn't skip the next lines of execution.

```
def run
    filename = "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}"
    file = Tempfile.new(filename)
    filepath = "#{file.path}"
    features = "features/login.feature"
    args = features.split.concat %w(-f html -o)
    args << "#{filepath}.html"
    Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute! # throws SystemExit Exception Status 0
    @output = file.read
    file.close
    file.unlink
    # More Code Below
    # # # # # # # # #
end
```

Comment: i don't see anything in Cucumber that is async so that shouldn't be happening.  `execute!` should be blocking

Comment: @Anthony The cucumber execute! throws a SystemExit with a status 0, so the exception occurs and the next line doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 3):

Two choices I see here, one is to catch the error and then read the file, such as:

```
begin
  Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!
rescue SystemExit => e
  if e.status == 0
    @value = file.read
  else
    raise e
  end
ensure
  file.close
  file.unlink
end
```

The other option is to make a runner class that inherits from the CLI and override `exit_ok`.

```
class Runner < Cucumber::Cli::Main
  def exit_ok
    #NOOP
  end
end

begin
  Runner.new(args).execute!
  @value = file.read
ensure
  file.close
  file.unlink
end
```

Comment: Thank you, awesome stuff.! @Anthony